# istringstream not parsing correctly

Tags: c++

I am using the following code to convert input strings to floats:

```
template <typename T>
T parseString(const std::string &s)
{
    T val;
    std::istringstream is(s.c_str());
    is >> val;

    return val;
}

float x = parseString<float>("0.1");
std::cout << std::setprecision(12) << x;
```

When I print x I get "0.10000000149" which is obviously wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Consider `std::stof`. And it is in no way "obviously wrong". Floating-point numbers are just not exact. C++ doesn't have any sort of `decimal` type, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [single-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) float data type is precise to about 8-9 decimal digits. You are printing it with 12 digits, so you can expect the last three to be off.

The reason why there's any difference at all is that 1/10 cannot be represented exactly as a binary fraction; there are dozens of questions with great answers on this site about this issue. The single-precision value closest to 1/10 is exactly 0.100000001490116119384765625.

Comment: I'm starting to hate floats.  I really am.

Comment: @mjr So use doubles. :P